# Does a eucalyptus tree cause damage to a building foundation?

Tags: trees, foundation

I planted a eucalyptus tree about 6 - 7 meters (20 - 22 feet) from my house.

Does this tree have an effect on my building foundation?

Answer (score 1):

Eucalyptus gunnii is a very large and fast growing tree if left unpruned; some of the other varieties don't get quite so large, but really, no eucalyptus should be planted with 40 or 50 feet (12.5 to 15 metres) of a building, because yes, it could affect foundations. Not to mention the mess it makes when larger with all the peeling scrolls of bark dropping everywhere...

Comment: May I add, brittle limbs, splitting branches.  I don't know where you live, but after our large wind storms you are guaranteed to see eucalyptus branches broken on the ground, trees split into two, you name it.   A beautiful tree with some major drawbacks.  As far as roots go, I do have a neighbour that is successfully growing eucalyptus trees in large tree boxes, I think somewhere around 1.5m tall and wide.  I was surprised it worked so well.  It is part of a deck designed when building the house.  I'm not sure what they did to anchor it all.

Answer (score 1):

No remove this tree immiediately the roots will destroy your footings in years to come, not to mention constantly clogging your drains and busting your water pipes. No gum tree should be planted within 100 metres of a house.

Answer (score 0):

I left a "broomstick" size oak about 5' from the foundation -mistake. In 20 yr it is 15" diameter. I have dug down along the foundation and cut all roots , does not affect the tree. If you want to keep the tree, you could try cuttings roots near the foundation.